# File copies and pastes blank data (or does not even copy and paste). Also loading is long

Tags: vba, excel

can someone please tell me why the data is not copying and pasting (or why it is copying and pasting blank data? Also is there a way to speed the automation?

```
 Sub GetDataCopyPaste()

 Dim wbTarget As Workbook 'where the data will be pasted
 Dim wbSource As Workbook 'where the data will be copied
 Dim StrName As String 'name of the source sheet

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'these statements help performance by disabling the self titled in each, remeber to re-enable at end of code
 Application.DisplayAlerts = False

 Set wbTarget = ActiveWorkbook 'set to the current workbook
 StrName = ActiveSheet.Name 'get active sheetname of workbook


 Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\jjordan\Desktop\Test Dir\Test File Test\metrics list.xlsx") 'opens Target workbook

 Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\jjordan\Desktop\Test Dir\MASTER\Weekly Logbook - 2016.xlsm") 'opens Source workbook

 wbSource.Sheets("IOS").Range("A1:E60").Value = wbTarget.Sheets("Sheet6").Range("A1:E60").Value 'copy & pastes source data onto Target workbook

 wbTarget.Save 'save workbook

 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 Application.DisplayAlerts = True

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This line is backwards

```
 wbSource.Sheets("IOS").Range("A1:E60").Value = wbTarget.Sheets("Sheet6").Range("A1:E60").Value 'copy & pastes source data onto Target workbook
```

You need

```
 wbTarget.Sheets("Sheet6").Range("A1:E60") = wbSource.Sheets("IOS").Range("A1:E60").value
```

I just tested and succeeded

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim myWB As Workbook
    Set myWB = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\raystafarian\Downloads\Book3.xlsx")
    Dim yourWB As Workbook
    Set yourWB = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\raystafarian\Downloads\Book2.xlsm")
    myWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C1:C4").Value = yourWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A4").Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Actually, I swapped it round before. Its still didnt work. I will change it again and give it a try.

Comment: Make sure you use .value on the source and make sure your targets are correct. step through and make sure they are open. If you needed the name of the worksheet in a variable, you never used that variable. Are you getting an error?

Comment: @JamesJordan It's very simple code - if it's not working then you're referencing something incorrectly or you have the wrong workbook active when you start the code.

Comment: I agree with you all. It appears to be very simple, but for some odd reason. The data is pasting blank cells/or not coping/pasting. @Raystafarian I have tried exactly your code. I only got blank cells.

Comment: @james put something in the destination cells and see if they are overwritten - I doubt they are which means nothing happens, not transferring blanks.

Comment: @Raystafarian I put some text in the destination column ("C1:C4"). The text was still there. Which means nothing was copied/pasted. Right?

Comment: Right nothing is happening. Double check your structure against mine for nuances, those are the key. forgetting `.value` on source will make nothing happen for instance.